# Bash - Read from file in the same directory as the script file

Tags: bash, file, cron

**Simple task i can't get to work:**

I have

> checkCsv.sh

in my user folder with these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATEFILE="filedate.txt"
echo $DATEFILE
logDate="$(<$DATEFILE)"
echo $logDate
```

in the same directory is the file

> filedate.txt

The problem is this error:
*checkCsv.sh: line 5: filedate.txt: No such file or directory*

But the file exists!

EDIT: Im running GNU Bash version 4.3.30(1)

---

Would appreciate any help

Comment: interesting - it works for me ( copy+paste and create filedate.txt ) on GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release. what version are you

Comment: It works for me too: `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Try to add echo $PWD in the script to see where it is looking for the file, or ls $PWD

Comment: $PWD outputs /home/debianvm

Comment: @amdixon i added the version im running to the main post.

Comment: Insert TARGET_DIR=$HOME; cd "$TARGET_DIR" as the first line of your script. And yes, cat "$DATEFILE" will be more helpful than echo "$DATEFILE" :)

Comment: @Minzkraut, I have tried too and could not get it to fail using bash 4.3-1.  I would suggest perhaps there is something wrong with your binutils or something else that is not quite installed correctly.  What OS are you on?

Comment: You've tagged this as `cron`; are you running the script from cron, and if so, what does the crontab entry look like?

Comment: i originally tried this on a mac, now i did the same on a debian machine and there is no error... just a blank line. @chepner the cron tag wasn't really meant to be there... im going to run this script as a cronjob later on... i was writing another question when i asked this (and forgot to delete the tag after "re writing" the whole post.

Comment: Relative pathnames are resolved using the current working directory, which isn't necessarily the directory containing `checkCsv.sh`. You mention `$PWD` is /home/debianvm when you run the script; is that the directory that contains the script and the data file?

Comment: it is... and using @drvtiny s method with cat instead of just echo worked... i didn't really change anything else tho. weird

Comment: @drvtiny coukld you please write your comment as the answer so i can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please, insert this code after the first line of your script:

  TARGET_DIR=$HOME

  # Replace $HOME with the path to filedate.txt if it is not located at $HOME...

  cd "$TARGET_DIR"
- For debug, IMHO, `cat "$DATEFILE"` will be more helpful than `echo "$DATEFILE"`